# Sort Drillthrough report

Tags: sorting, ssas, ssas-2008, drillthrough

I've got a problem with the Drillthrough Action is SSAS 2008.

I want to set the sort order of the Drillthrough Report by a specific drillthrough column, but I can't find a solution for the problem. I was searching for it, but couldn't find anything.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gathered further information to this question and it seems, like this is not possible.
If there's anyone who also needs this feature in his detail-reports he might give feedback at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback

Regards,

T.K.